# AS3 problems with cos / sin - doesn't fire in the direction i want

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, trigonometry

Ok so i have a space shooter game, seen from above. The ship travels upward (-y) and rotates slightly when moved left and right with the mouse. The maximum rotation is between -10 and 10, with easing of * 0.5.
To get the "bullets" to fire in the same direction the ship is facing, i am trying to use the cos sin formulas. It works great as long as the ship's rotation is -5 or 5 (-10 * 0.5, 10 * 0.5), but as soon as the rotation approaches 0, it starts firing all over the place:)

I have read that i need to convert degrees into radians to be able to use cos and sin, and i have tried that - the best result i got from that was that it only fired left or right, depending on the rotation, with no variation in angle.

Now im new to AS of course, so apologize for comprehensible code:)

Can anyone help me figure out why the angle works fine at -5 and 5, but gets crazy when it closes in on 0?

Thanks guys!

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var spaceship_mc:spaceship = new spaceship();

stage.addChild(spaceship_mc);

spaceship_mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
spaceship_mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,shipMovement);


function shipMovement(event:Event):void 
{

var dx:int = spaceship_mc.x - mouseX;
var dy:int = spaceship_mc.y - mouseY;
spaceship_mc.x -= dx / 15;
spaceship_mc.y -= dy /20;


if (dx >= -10 && dx <= 0) 
{
    spaceship_mc.rotation = -dx * 0.5;
}
else if (dx >= 0 && dx <= 10) 
{
    spaceship_mc.rotation = dx * -0.5;
}
else if (dx > -10) 
{
    spaceship_mc.rotation = -10 * 0.5;
}
else if (dx < 10) 
{
    spaceship_mc.rotation = 10 * 0.5;
}


if (spaceship_mc.rotation > 0)
{
    spaceship_mc.scaleX = 1-(0.05 * spaceship_mc.rotation);
}
if (spaceship_mc.rotation < 0)
{
    spaceship_mc.scaleX = 1-(0.05 * -(spaceship_mc.rotation));
}


    if (dy >= 0 && dy < 22 )
{
    spaceship_mc.afterburner_mc.y = 22;
}
else if (dy >= 22 && dy <= 32)
{
    spaceship_mc.afterburner_mc.y = dy;
}
else if (dy > 32)
{
    spaceship_mc.afterburner_mc.y = 32;
}
else if (dy < 0)
{
    spaceship_mc.afterburner_mc.y = 22;
}


var spaceshipHalfWidth:uint = spaceship_mc.width/2;
var spaceshipHalfHeight:uint = spaceship_mc.height/2;


if (spaceship_mc.x + spaceshipHalfWidth > stage.stageWidth) 
{
    spaceship_mc.x = stage.stageWidth - spaceshipHalfWidth;
}
else if (spaceship_mc.x - spaceshipHalfWidth < 0) 
{        
    spaceship_mc.x = 0 + spaceshipHalfWidth;    
}      
if (spaceship_mc.y - spaceshipHalfHeight < 0) 
{        
    spaceship_mc.y = 0 + spaceshipHalfHeight;    
}    
else if (spaceship_mc.y + spaceshipHalfHeight > stage.stageHeight) 
{
    spaceship_mc.y = stage.stageHeight - spaceshipHalfHeight;
}
}


addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, skyt);


function skyt(e:MouseEvent):void
{
nyttSkudd();
}


function nyttSkudd()
{
var leftPhoton_mc:photon = new photon();
var rightPhoton_mc:photon = new photon();

leftPhoton_mc.x = spaceship_mc.x - 25;
leftPhoton_mc.y = spaceship_mc.y - 10;

rightPhoton_mc.x = spaceship_mc.x + 16;
rightPhoton_mc.y = spaceship_mc.y - 10;

leftPhoton_mc.rotation = spaceship_mc.rotation;
rightPhoton_mc.rotation = spaceship_mc.rotation;

addChild(leftPhoton_mc);
addChild(rightPhoton_mc);
addChild(spaceship_mc);

leftPhoton_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, skudd);
rightPhoton_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, skudd);
}


function skudd(e:Event):void
{   
var photonAngle = e.target.rotation;
var photonSpeed = 10;

if (photonAngle == 0)
{
    e.target.y -= photonSpeed;
}
else if (photonAngle > 0)
{
    e.target.x += photonSpeed * Math.cos(photonAngle);
    e.target.y += photonSpeed * Math.sin(photonAngle);      
}
else if (photonAngle < 0)
{
    e.target.x -= photonSpeed * Math.cos(photonAngle);
    e.target.y -= photonSpeed * Math.sin(photonAngle);
}

if (e.target.y < 0 || e.target.y > 400)
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, skudd);
    e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
}
}
```

Comment: Define what the problem is exactly

Comment: To get the "bullets" to fire in the same direction the ship is facing, i am trying to use the cos sin formulas. It works great as long as the ship's rotation is -5 or 5 (-10 * 0.5, 10 * 0.5), but as soon as the rotation approaches 0, it starts firing all over the place:)

Comment: "all over the place" was the necessary phrase ;)

Comment: Hehe if there is any other information i can give you for you to be able to help me out, just let me know!:)

Answer (score 2):

photonAngle is in degrees but Math.sin/cos takes radians. so you need the following conversion.

```
var photonAngle = e.target.rotation * Math.PI / 180.0;
```

also

```
e.target.x += photonSpeed * Math.cos(photonAngle);
e.target.y += photonSpeed * Math.sin(photonAngle);
```

is sufficient you don't need the if/else statements:

```
if (photonAngle == 0)
{
    e.target.y -= photonSpeed;
}
else if (photonAngle > 0)
{
    e.target.x += photonSpeed * Math.cos(photonAngle);
    e.target.y += photonSpeed * Math.sin(photonAngle);      
}
else if (photonAngle < 0)
{
    e.target.x -= photonSpeed * Math.cos(photonAngle);
    e.target.y -= photonSpeed * Math.sin(photonAngle);
}
```

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have already tried converting to radians. Tried it again since you mentioned 180.0 and i tried it using 180. Still - same result i'm afraid - it fires sideways left or right (+ or - on the x-axis).
Deleting the if / else if statements causes it to only fire right (+ x-axis).
Please notice the spaceship_mc.rotation statements further up the code. Can the problem be related to those? Or do you have any other ideas?
Grateful for help!